# presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL not recognized in WatchKit project

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, watchos, watchos-2

I have an existing project for WatchKit and with the new WatchOS release Apple have implemented a method called `presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL` to record audio from AppleWatch.

When I call this method I have two compilations errors. I imagine that I have to add or include something more but I don't know what I have to change in my project.

[image]

Errors:

```
/path/myProject WatchKit Extension/AWMessagesController.m:278:56: 'WKAudioRecordingPresetWideBandSpeech' is unavailable: not available on iOS

/path/myProject WatchKit Extension/AWMessagesController.m:277:11: 'presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL:preset:maximumDuration:actionTitle:completion:' is unavailable: not available on iOS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL` cannot be used in an iOS extension. You have to migrate your code appropriately (e.g., copy files to the watch target). Refer to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/UpdatetheAppCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH6-SW1).